# How to force remote Documents folder on OneDrive to sync with different folder than default?

Tags: windows-10, sync, onedrive, localization

I have enabled backup of my Windows Documents folder to OneDrive using this window:

[image: backup onedrive]

But the name of Documents folder on my system is in different language and it is not `Documents` but `Dokumenty`.
As a result I have a `Documents` folder that contains the data and a second empty `Dokumenty` folder on my PC.

[image: Documents folders]

Is there a fix that allows me to keep the remote OneDrive folder name `Documents` - i.e. not changing this folder online - but to force to sync with proper folder on my PC in my language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible just to edit the location of Documents like this, that's what the dialog does:

[image: Docs properties]

---

I have found out that I can enable the same functionality as the dialog window just by editing registry values:

```
\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

Changing values for `{F42EE2D3-909F-4907-8871-4C22FC0BF756}` (Local Documents) and `Personal` to the local folder of OneDrive synced Documents, e.g.

```
C:\Users\myself\OneDrive - MyCompany\Documents
```

But still the visible name of the folder remained `Documents` but it should have been in my language `Dokumenty`...

Another thing I had to do was to copy `desktop.ini` file from `C:\users\myself\documents` to `C:\Users\myself\OneDrive - MyCompany\Documents`. It fixed the visible folder name and icon in explorer. Of course restarting explorer.exe or logoff/logon was necessary.

The content of Desktop.ini was:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\windows.storage.dll,-21770
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-112
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-235
```

But I could have used instead my desired name directly:

```
LocalizedResourceName=Dokumenty
```